# Object returning an extra NULL array inside

Tags: php, api, twig, slim

So I've built a simple API with Slim framework, while using one Middleware for validation from here https://github.com/Respect/Validation via a function as followed through this guide:

https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/slim-3-authentication/769
https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/slim-3-authentication/770

Everything seems to be alright except of one specific thing:

By this guide I should be able to validate my forms and their input and then on my Twig page print these errors for example by doing this `{{ errors | json_encode }}` (for testing), the problem is that even though the validate function itself works as it should I can't seem to get the errors as they always return null.

By using `var_dump` I've noticed that the "errors" are there, but the format seems a bit different than the one shown in the guide video as in my var_dump there seem to be an extra array? (not sure) showing `NULL`, and only after that there are other arrays containing these errors so I would assume that would be the reason of why it's not working?

Here is an example of what I get when I var_dump it:

```
object(App\Validation\Validator)#79 (2) { ["errors":protected]=> NULL [""]=> array(1) { ["uniquevisitors"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(30) "Uniquevisitors must be numeric" [1]=> string(31) "Uniquevisitors must be positive" } } }
```

And that's when I var_dump it with get_object_vars:

```
array(1) { [""]=> array(1) { ["uniquevisitors"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(30) "Uniquevisitors must be numeric" [1]=> string(31) "Uniquevisitors must be positive" } } }
```

I don't think the `{ ["errors":protected]=> NULL [""]=>`  should be there.
My code is exactly as in that guide yet the results it yields for him are slightly different. The errors about the 'uniquevisitors' are how it should be, but I don't think that null should be there which I think may be the reason why my Twig template can't read it and always shows `null`, but I may be wrong.

Can something be wrong with the usage of global and/or session within that middleware? JFYI I use other middleware too, but this has been this way since I added it and just in case I've ran it again on another "clean" slim and got the same output. When I did some research I've found one case with exact same issue but with no answer so I believe something may be off with the code? Or maybe with my environment? I am running it locally by using xampp.

---

middleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

class Middleware {
    protected $container;

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

ValidationErrorsMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

class ValidationErrorsMiddleware extends Middleware {
    protected $container;

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
        $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('errors', $_SESSION['errors']);
        unset($_SESSION['errors']);
    }
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        return $response;
    }
    }
```

Validator.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Validation;

use Respect\Validation\Validator as Respect;
use Respect\Validation\Exceptions\NestedValidationException;

class Validator {

protected $errors;

    public function validate($request, array $rules) {

        foreach($rules as $field => $rule) {
            try {
                $rule->setName(ucfirst($field))->assert($request->getParam($field));
            } catch (NestedValidationException $e) {
                $errors='';
                $this->$errors[$field] = $e->getMessages();
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['errors'] = $this->errors;
        return $this;
    }
    public function failed(){
        $errors='';
        return !empty($this->$errors);
    }
}
```

For some reason when I want to post these errors respectively inside of a Twig form by using `{{ errors.field }}` it's staying blank or having null, (same with `errors | json_encode` it stays null). Validation itself works, and `var_dump` shows that there are these errors but for some reason I can't get them posted on twig, and I assume it's because my 'errors' contains some extra Null that shouldn't be there.

I am using same code that was posted on that guide that I've mentioned in my first post, and it seem to work for this guy but not for me.

Comment: Not sure why u'd retag this question with `twig` as this has nothing to do with `twig`.

Comment: Show some actual code please. A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: @jmattheis Not sure if you get the notification when I post an 'answer' type of message so pinging you this way just in case, thanks!

Comment: @user3540359 ... Yes, but this has nothing to do with `twig` itself.. `twig` is not the problem your `errors` variable is incorrect

Comment: @DarkBee Do you know what's exactly the issue with that errors variable? I am not sure what's the problem there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validator is having some issues, at this point you are trying to assign errors to the dynamic property`$errors`,

```
$errors = '';
$this->$errors[$field] = $e->getMessages();
```

Roughly "translated" this would mean, add the output of `$e->getMessages()` to the property `$this->{empty string}` as `$errors` is defined as `""` and which is the reasons of the "weird" output you are having with `var_dump`

What you actually are looking for is this,

```
$this->errors[$field] = $e->getMessages();
```

Same goes for your `validate` function

```
public function failed(){
    return !empty($this->errors); //and not $this->$errors
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that $errors = ''; is responsible for the break? I was thinking of that before but even without it I am facing the same issue, actually originally I didn't even have that there but added it as sometimes code was throwing 'undefined variable' error aside of this one. After removing the errors string it's still the same.

Comment: Hence I wrote `$this->errors` and not `$this->$errors`, which would indeed result in that notice when omtting `$errors = '';`

Comment: I knew that before but now it's confirmed - I am dumb. Now it works, thanks a lot mate :)